# Acoustic fingerstyle uneven sound

Tags: guitar, beginner, fingerstyle-guitar

I'm a beginner at fingerstyle guitar. When I play with longer nails, I get a nice crisp sound, but the volume is uneven based on which finger I use. Sometimes I get this horribly loud/scraping sound (usually from the index finger) that just overpowers the other strings. I'm using a steel-string guitar.

Is this normal for a beginner? How do I get a more even sound? I think the angle of my hand is problematic (it's usually at 45 degrees). When I play perpendicularly to the strings, the volume is more even, but it's awkward on my wrists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens because not all your fingers have the same strength and you don't know how to control your finger strength. It's pretty common for a beginner, nothing to worry about.

In order to get an evenly balanced sound on all of the fingers, try working only with the fingers on open strings. Play all of the fingers and try to use the same strength. It will seem a bit boring at first, because you'll have to think about the strength on each and every finger, but after some practice, it'll come naturally to you.

Μy guess is that your thumb, index and middle fingers have more strength than the others, so you might have to work on the other two a bit more.